# ee.Algorithms.If() in Google Earth Engine trueCase causing an error even though it should be entering falseCase

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a simple function where I am trying to define a geometry based on a simple condition, whether the feature `roi` exists (condition is *true* if it exists, *false* if it does not).

```
var getShape = function(params){ 
  // Parameters
  var roi = params.roi
  var selectedStates = params.selectedStates
  // Get state geometry
  var selectedStatesGeometry = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1")
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('ADM1_NAME', selectedStates))
    .geometry()
  // Calculate shape  
  var baseShape = ee.Geometry(
    ee.Algorithms.If({ // If roi exists
      condition: roi,
      // then return roi geometry
      trueCase: roi.geometry(ee.ErrorMargin(100)),
      // if not return state borders
      falseCase: selectedStatesGeometry
    })
  )
  return baseShape
}
// Apply function
var test = getShape({
  roi: null,
  selectedStates: ['Oaxaca'],
})
print(test)
Map.addLayer(test)
```

The issue is that no matter if the condition is true or false the script fails, stating `Cannot read property 'geometry' of null`. This error is coming from the trueCase, which is understandable since `roi` does not exist. This defeats the entire purpose of the function, since I am trying to handle cases where `roi` does not exist. However, I know for a fact the algorithms is 'entering' falseCase, because if I change the outcome of trueCase to a dummy geometry it will output the state borders and not the dummy geometry (at is should).

I am trying to avoid using an if/else loop since it is client-side function which implies I would have to evaluate the outputs, which is bad practice, however I'm not sure I have a choice at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an Object to `ee.Algorithms.If()`:

```
{
  ...
  trueCase: roi.geometry(ee.ErrorMargin(100))
  ...
}
```

When you great this object, `roi.geometry(ee.ErrorMargin(100))` will get invoked. Since `roi` is `null`, you get an error before `ee.Algorithms.If()` is even invoked.

Comment: Wow that is so frustrating! This basically forces us to use a client-side if() loop even if that means having to evaluate values which really slows down the code.. How unfortunate. Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: I found that there usually are ways around this, but how to do that is very much context specific. Oftentimes I end up introducing lists or collection and map, filter, or reduce. In your test function, you do have a client-side `null`, so you're fine to do client-side null-check. `(roi || selectedStatesCollection).geometry()` Maybe that's not the case in the real script?

Comment: That's a good idea actually, thanks!